# Function pointer type definition

Tags: c, function, pointers

What is the difference between the following two type defines?

```
1. typedef char * (*fnptr)( void );
2. typedef char * fnptr( void );
```

One is a type for a pointer to a function and other one is a type for a function. For a function with name fn_name, both fn_name and &fn_name are pointers to the function (the address of the first instruction).  Is this correct?

Using 2 I can replace the following line in my code:

```
char *getsome( void );
```

by:

```
fnptr getsome;
```

Using 1 in the manner mentioned above crashes the program. If I use 1, then i have to define a variable g of type fnptr and set it equal to getsome to make the program working again.

Comment: You seem already to have answered the only question you posed.  What, then, do you want to know?

Comment: Just a confirmation, if that was correct, and I am not overlooking anything subtle. Thanks,

Comment: You're basically correct.  But nobody declares functions using a typedef instead of explicitly writing the return and argument types.   So don't do `fnptr getsome;`.

Comment: @JohnZwinck The OpenGL ES 2.0 header file uses function pointer typedefs.

Comment: @Cppplus1: So what?  Nobody does that.  I think the colloquial meaning of "nobody" is understood.